# Suitable component query for tbar of a panel in Extjs

Tags: extjs4.2, component-query

I have a panel and in top bar of this panel I have some buttons.
I select the button below:

```
mypanel button[action=draw]
```

But I want to select the button from tbar of panel.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really difficult to understand what you ask. The selector looks fine. It selects a button with action 'draw' inside the panel, it can be inside the tbar or not.

If you have two `button[action=draw]` inside the panel, you can select the one in tbar with `mypanel toolbar button[action=draw]`.

If you have a reference of the toolbar in a variable, do it like this : `tbar.down('button[action=draw]')`